# Using the TeamViewer API

Tags: c#, winforms, teamviewer

I am looking to create a C# application that will report on the connections that we make to customers. I am looking into the [TeamViewer API](http://downloadeu3.teamviewer.com/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf), but I cannot get the code below to authenticate:

```cs
string accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string apiVersion = "v1";
string tvApiBaseUrl = "https://webapi.teamviewer.com";
string address = tvApiBaseUrl + "/api/" + apiVersion + "/reports/connections";

try
{
    // Create the web request  
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Headers.Add("Bearer", accessToken);
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse webResp = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Do nothing for now
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The exception that is thrown is: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Comment: Where are you get your accessToken?

Comment: I am using the accessToken that was provided in the Management console,. It works with the standard vb-script files that are provided by TeamViewer.

Comment: You're not including the `Authorization` header.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and make sure your requests include the authorization header.

**All API requests need to include the "Authorization" header if the API function requires an access token.**

Example

```
GET /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1 
Host: webapi.teamviewer.com 
Authorization: Bearer 54213-2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWp
```

Also examine what they are sending you back, it may provide a clue.

**UPDATE**

Try this change

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```